# Trim text by length and insert rows; include empty cells if already exist

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

For column C, I need to trim text by length and insert rows, and if empty cells already exist in column C, carry them over. Next, I need to create empty cells for columns A & B from the new cells created in column C by the trim.  Last, if there is data in Column A & B, but Column C has no data, the data from A & B should be carried over. Currently, it doesn't.

```
Sub test()
Dim txt As String, temp As String, colA As String, colB As String
Dim a, b() As String, n, i As Long
Const myLen As Long = 70
a = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim b(1 To Rows.Count, 1 To 3)
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    If a(i, 1) <> "" Then
        colA = a(i, 1)
        colB = a(i, 2)
        txt = Trim(a(i, 3))
        Do While Len(txt)
            If Len(txt) <= myLen Then
                temp = txt
            Else
                temp = Left$(txt, InStrRev(txt, " ", myLen))
            End If
            If temp = "" Then Exit Do
            n = n + 1
            b(n, 1) = colA: b(n, 2) = colB
            b(n, 3) = Trim(temp)
            txt = Trim(Mid$(txt, Len(temp) + 1))
        Loop
    End If
Next
Range("e1").Resize(n, 3).Value = b
End Sub
```

[What code is doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cop4K.png)
[What code should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NQbe.png)

I tried to work on using not with "" and the ReDim.

Comment: If your code doesn't already do what you want, we can't use it as a guide for what you want, so you'll need to provide more detail around what it's *supposed* to do, including before/after screenshots or data tables if possible.

Comment: I included an example.

Answer (score 0):

- Comment out `If a(i, 1) <> "" Then` and `End If` to include blank cells on Col A.
- Const `MAX_CNT` represents the maximum number of rows after splitting each row of data.
- If you resize the array using `Redim` after the first Redim, it can only change the `last` dimension. It's easier to declare a large enough array initially to handle the data.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim txt As String, temp As String, colA As String, colB As String
    Dim a, b() As String, n, i As Long
    Const myLen As Long = 70
    Const MAX_CNT As Long = 10  ' modify as needed
    a = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim b(1 To Rows.Count * MAX_CNT, 1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
'        If a(i, 1) <> "" Then ' ** remove
            colA = a(i, 1)
            colB = a(i, 2)
            txt = Trim(a(i, 3))
            Do While Len(txt)
                If Len(txt) <= myLen Then
                    temp = txt
                Else
                    temp = Left$(txt, InStrRev(txt, " ", myLen))
                End If
                If temp = "" Then Exit Do
                n = n + 1
                b(n, 1) = colA
                b(n, 2) = colB
                b(n, 3) = Trim(temp)
                txt = Trim(Mid$(txt, Len(temp) + 1))
            Loop
'        End If ' ** remove
    Next
    Range("e1").Resize(n, 3).Value = b
End Sub
```